# Redis with NodeJS - creating a set of ten items

Tags: node.js, http, angular, redis

I am currently building a small application in Angular2, NodeJS and Redis where user information is to be stored in the Redis instance. I am relatively new to Redis and am having trouble trying to visualise the functionality I am needing to create.

A user enters a word via the Angular2 frontend in an input form. The word is then converted to a different string then these values are stored in the form of an object in storage (Redis). Only the last 10 items are needed to be stored so therefore the storage DB needs to be 10 in length with the newest item being appended to the collection and the last item being trimmed if the length is already 10.

I am having difficulty implementing this in Redis and my Redis commands in the NodeJS layer don't seem to be doing what I want them to do.

Here is the NodeJS controller that handles the user input:

```
var Config = require(global.appRoot + '/Config.js');
var redisClient = require('../lib/redisConnection');

function Storage() {
    this.__objectName = 'Storage';
}

Storage.prototype.storeTerm = function(req, res, next) {
    var word = req.body.word;
    var newWord = req.body.newWord;
    var hashToStore = {
        word:  newWord
    };
    redisClient.hmset(['words', word], function(err, reply) {
        if(err) {
            res.json('Error:' + err);
        } else {
            res.json(reply);
        }
    });
};

module.exports = Storage;
```

As you can see, the user input is sent to this function from the Angular2 http callm then the values parsed, put into the object hashToStore then I am attempting to save this in a hash called 'words'. This doesn't seem to work and  am unsure as to how to implement the 10 limit functionality.

Can anyone please tell me if this is correct or where I am going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [rpush](https://redis.io/commands/rpush) command instead of `hmset`. `rpush` returns length of list after insertion so you can easy apply 10 items limit with [lpop](https://redis.io/commands/lpop)

```
redisClient.rpush('your_list_name', newWord, function(err, reply) {
    if(err) {
        res.json('Error:' + err);
    } else {
        if(reply > 10) {
            redisClient.lpop('your_list_name');
        }
        res.json({status: "ok"}); // send some kinde of status
    }
});
```

Comment: I am storing an object and thought hmet was the only way of storing objects in Redis? Am I incorrect?

Comment: Actually, you'd want to also look at `LTRIM` to keep the list capped

Comment: @devoncrazylegs you can use `JSON.stringify` to store Objects as Strings